# When to draw controls manually and when to add via interface builder?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I'm learning iOS and I've gone through a few tutorials now, and one or two of them had you draw all the controls in the IB, and one or two of them had you create them all programmatically.

This leads me to wonder whether I can safely mix and match these approaches. I know the answer is yes, of course, since it would make no sense otherwise.

But what are the advantages/disadvantages? Particularly with regard to proportions and sizing for different screens, that bit is still an obstacle to me as a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mainly a matter of taste. I like to make my controls in code others prefer the Interface Builder. I see the following advantages for the Interface Builder:

1. More visual. You can see how you interface will look like while you put it together.
2. You can use the Preview assistant editor and see you interface without compiling.
3. You don't have to remember what the options are called because you can scan the checkboxes for what you are searching.
4. You can faster prototype with storyboards.
5. Maybe your designer can learn to build the interface using storyboards.

The advantages for code are:

1. No context shift. All you do is coding.
2. Still you have less merge conflicts when you are working with a team on a project.
3. All the options are in one place. In Interface Builder you have to click through all the inspectors to find what you are searching for.
4. It's easier to post code than screenshots in case you need help on Stackoverflow ;).
5. If you finde code on github you can see without downloading how the interface is build.
6. I had a few times that a project could not be opened by Xcode when I opened it in a beta of Xcode because the Interface Builder file structure had been changed.
7. Code is easier to refactor than storyboards (Thanks @Spectravideo328 for the suggestion in the comments).
8. It is impossible to inherit from a storyboard scene. I code you can easily make subclasses to reuse code. Using a storyboard you have to make two scenes even if they share 90% of their UI elements.

One thing which is very important: Don't put all you screens in one storyboard. Try to keep the storyboards small. Something between 1-6 screens is working for me with good performance.

Comment: Key here is less merge conflicts. XML diff conflict resolution is a life altering event. I would add as an advantage of code the ability to refactor classes.

Answer (score 0):

There are no such thing like advantages or disadvantages. Just take a example. if you already have those controls to use it via Xcode. why will you code it. We only code things when we need to make special controls or you can edit your controls by connecting your controls to the code(you can google it "how to connect buttons in iOS"). In short, you only create controls when its kind of a special control which is not pre build in Xcode.

Comment: There are advantages and disadvantages. Other wise it would be strange that some prefer one over the other.

Comment: let you know. its a common sense thing that no one would make a control which is pre made in interface builder